# Put highchart on the very start of the graphic

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to make some graphics. There are 3 graphics inside the same highchart, but my problem is that the highchart start with some padding at the left, like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this: (Edited with photoshop)

[image]

Help please

Comment: Try adjusting the `maxPadding` option (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding) and the `startOnTick` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick).  If these can't get you close you may be forced to set an explicit min.

Answer (score 0):

That question has been asked several times (I don't remember link), but in general don't use categorized xAxis, but use standard linear with specific label formatter, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/266/

```
    var categories = ['01/02/2012','01/03/2012','01/04/2012','01/05/2012','01/06/2012','01/07/2012'];

var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container2'
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return categories[this.value];   
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
});
```

Now you can play around with `startOnTick` and `minPadding`.  For categorized axis this is not possible to change space distribution - it's always evenly divided between all points.